# Retain edittext contents inside recyclerview

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have a requirement wherein I have to render a form from api which consists of different user input data such as name, data of birth, selection of country etc. For gathering this information from the user I am using multiple view types such as EditText, DatePicker, Spinner as view types inside RecyclerView with help of [AdapterDelegates](https://github.com/sockeqwe/AdapterDelegates). The problem I am facing right now is retaining the contents of these view types if there are more than 6 items. Any idea on how to stop RecyclerView from recycling the view types and retaining its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with setItemViewCacheSize(int) to the recycler but I don't think its the best practise.

Regards

Comment: This may "work", but it defeats the recycling purpose of `RecyclerView`. You're telling the system to retain all views in memory, and never recycle them.

Comment: Well there might be strong reasoning behind why this method was added to the RecyclerView and that reason is exactly why I need it :D